# AngularJs filter with a conditional condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am not sure if this is possible, but any insight would be much appreciated.

I am trying to filter a duration for an album with a custom angularJs filter that is already provided for me. I want to either show hours if its available or not to show it at all if its not. I tried using something like:

```
<span>{{ media.duration | peDateFormatFilter: ((HH > 0) ? {"HH:mm:ss":{ "def": "H[ hrs] mm[ mins]"}} : "mm:ss":{ "def": "mm[ mins])} }}</span>
```

The problem with that is it keeps erring out in the browser when I run it with:

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: media.duration | peDateFormatFilter: ((HH > 0) ? "HH:mm:ss":{ "def": "H[ hrs] mm[ mins]"
```

I am not sure what this could be? Is the best solution for me just to create another custom filter for my code?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is the best solution indeed, this really looks ugly even if you would make it work, who would maintain this? it would be so hard to know what you meant even for yourself in few months.

Comment: Create a custom filter. The error occurs as this is an expression and in expressions you can't use conditionals: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression (No Control Flow Statements)

Comment: its angularjs or angular?

Comment: what is the data format of the duration?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I added two `<span ng-if`s to the page, which fixes the issue at hand.

```
                                            <span ng-if="media.duration.substr(0,2) != 00">{{ media.duration | peDateFormatFilter:"HH:mm:ss":{ "def": "H[ hrs] mm[ mins]"} }}</span>
                                            <span ng-if="media.duration.substr(0,2) == 00">{{ media.duration | peDateFormatFilter:"HH:mm:ss":{ "def": "mm[ mins]"} }}</span>
```

Thanks for looking at this!